# turbo frame tag for order_item quantity update rendering text on submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks, turbo

I am trying to build a frame_tag where only the order quantity will be updated when the add/remove order item button is clicked.

I am building a menu system and I have the add product to order items and remove product from order items.

In between them I have the quantity

```
<% @quantity = current_order.order_items.where(product_id: 
cp.id).count %>
```

Then I have made a partial

```
<%= render "products/quantity" %>
```

Containing

```
<p class="mt-3 float-end oi-qty" style="width: 10%;"><%= 
@quantity %></p>
```

I have tried a couple of examples online and the closest I have got to anything is the following appears as plain text when button is submitted:

```
<turbo-stream action="replace" target="quantity"><template><p 
class="mt-3 float-end oi-qty" style="width: 10%;"></p>
</template></turbo-stream>
```

The Menu:

[image: The Menu]

OrderItemsController

```
def create
@order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_params)
if @order.save
session[:order_id] = @order.id

render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace("quantity", 
  partial: 'products/quantity')
end 
end
```

Products page

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "quantity" do %>
<div id="quantity">
  <%= render "products/quantity" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think you need to explain better what's your problem and what's the result your searching for.

Comment: @RafaelMoreira When I click the plus/minus button the quantity updates but it also refreshes the full page. So if a customer is halfway down the menu and adds an item it will refresh them to the top of the page. I am trying to make it so that when they add the item the page stays in the same place but the quantity partial updates the quantity so they can seamlessly navigate the menu without scrolling down every time

Comment: If you call a partial using the OrderItemsController#create, you should add the @quantity variable there.

Also, here's a good link to help you with the turbo_stream: https://www.hotrails.dev/turbo-rails/turbo-frames-and-turbo-streams